# ORDER BY statement in Hive on Tez throws OOM Exception

Tags: hadoop, hive, out-of-memory, hiveql, apache-tez

I'm trying to use ORDER BY to find the earliest time an entry has been made in my table in Hive. The statement looks like this

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, timeiss
FROM iss
ORDER BY timeiss
LIMIT 10;
```

This gives me an error message that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Qp9.png

Just to show you how a SELECT statement works without the ORDER BY:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOOEj.png

```
latitude    longitude   timeiss
-26.6542    -96.9894    2018-11-28 10:13:42
-39.6293    -80.6984    2018-11-28 10:18:45
```

I got almost the same error when trying

```
SELECT MIN(timeiss)
FROM iss
```

timeiss is a string btw.

**Here's the full error message as text**

> java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED:
>   Execution Error, return code 2 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed,
>   vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1541164145004_0025_1_00,
>   diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1541164145004_0025_1_00_000000,
>   diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running
>   task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
>   space at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:159)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
>   at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.(HeapByteBuffer.java:57) at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335) at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.PipelinedSorter.(PipelinedSorter.java:173)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.PipelinedSorter.(PipelinedSorter.java:117)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.start(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:142)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:138)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
>   ... 14 more ], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Failure while
>   running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:159)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
>   at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.(HeapByteBuffer.java:57) at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335) at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.PipelinedSorter.(PipelinedSorter.java:173)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.PipelinedSorter.(PipelinedSorter.java:117)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.start(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:142)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:138)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
>   ... 14 more ], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Failure while
>   running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:159)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
>   at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.(HeapByteBuffer.java:57) at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335) at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.PipelinedSorter.(PipelinedSorter.java:173)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.PipelinedSorter.(PipelinedSorter.java:117)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.start(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:142)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:138)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
>   ... 14 more ], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Failure while
>   running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:159)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
>   at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.(HeapByteBuffer.java:57) at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335) at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.PipelinedSorter.(PipelinedSorter.java:173)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.PipelinedSorter.(PipelinedSorter.java:117)
>   at
>   org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.start(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:142)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:138)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
>   ... 14 more ]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE,
>   failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1541164145004_0025_1_00
>   [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]Vertex killed,
>   vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1541164145004_0025_1_01,
>   diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did
>   not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:1,
>   Vertex vertex_1541164145004_0025_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due
>   to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE.
>   failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1

Comment: Do you mean the error message? I'm new to this site so I'm not sure if it would have been fine if I just posted an error message of like 50 lines

Answer (score 1):

Map1 vertex is failing with OOM Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
>   space at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor

Try to increase Mapper container and JVM memory.

Like this:

```
set hive.tez.container.size=9216;
set hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx6144m;
```

But better check you current container and java heap size and increase it accordingly.
Read this article for more details: [Demystifying Tez Memory Tuning](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/14309/demystify-tez-tuning-step-by-step.html)